# Why am I seeing a red box around messages in Skype after upgrading?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I have recently upgraded to a new Windows 10 PC and the 'new' Skype.  Version details, in case it is relevant:

[image]

There's a new 'feature' that is driving me crazy.  I'm not sure if it's a Skype behaviour or a Windows 10 thing, but I haven't seen it in any other applications...

Every so often, for no apparent reason, a red box appears.  Often around a message (maybe an unread message?) but sometimes around the "Here's where the unread messages begin!" line, and sometimes around the text entry box, like this:
[image]

It... doesn't provide any actual information, and is incredibly distracting.  If I tap things a bit it generally disappears eventually, but I would prefer it not appear in the first place if possible.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: That is a Windows 10 assistance utility such as magnifier or narrator you likely started by holding a hotkey combination. Open Settings and find Ease of Access and see if any of the items are enabled. Another possibility is the snipping tool which can highlight fields for creating documentation and how-to documents.

Comment: @music2myear It's possible you're right, but I have checked the Ease of Access settings and everything seems to be turned off; so if it is one, I can't find it there.  And as I said, I haven't seen the behaviour in any other application though, just Skype...

Answer (score 0):

I just had it and found this thread looking for ways to get rid of it.

In trying to find the Skype Settings, I noticed that the Notifications icon top left was indicating that I had a new notification.

Clicked to see the notification and the red box has disappeared. So maybe it's just highlighting that you have unread notifications?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out to be a faulty cable on one of my usb controllers causing the connection to go in and out and for the focus to change based on perceived input.  Unplugging the controller fixed it.  Looks like I need a new s-video cable.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found the fix, go to focus assistant settings (windows) and disable automatic rules

Comment: Can you elaborate? Please explain why the OP is getting the red box and why you think this will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this question as I had the same annoying issue.

A little tinkering and I found that if you go in to Skype, Settings and select the Appearance tab on the left, and then set the Modes to "Use system setting", and then go to the Messaging tab and set "Text size" to Normal (mine was already set to that, so I just selected another size and then set it back again).

I am not sure which of the 2 changes fixed the issue, or why for that matter, but the annoying red box has now vanished.

Hope this helps.

** UPDATE **
Looks like the issue occurs when you open/restore Skype by clicking on a notification bubble. If you open/restore Skype by clicking the application in the taskbar, it does not happen.

Opening the settings window and closing it seams to fix the issue until next time you click on a notification bubble.

Comment: Scrap that.  It has returned.  Just opening the settings window removed the red boxes temporarily.

I think that they start showing when you open Skype by clicking on a notification bubble.  In fact, while typing this comment I have just confirmed that.  If you open Skype by clicking on a notification, the red boxes start showing. If you open Skype by just clicking the application on the taskbar, they do not appear.

Feels like a bug to me (unless there is some hidden meaning that us mortals do not understand).